# Is there a way to mouseenter event layerd elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have 2 circles one over the other (intersecting), is there a way to have them both access mouseover, mouseenter, and mouseleave? I want them to stay independent from each other, but when the cursor goes over both they should both change color.

If my cursor is only over red circle, then only red should change, and if my cursor is on blue then only blue should change. If my cursor is on both (intersection) then both should change color. These circles will be moving so I don't want a static solution for the intersection.

I know pointer-events: none; will remove the functionality allowing me to access the lower layer, but I want them to both be active.

```
CIRCLE.addEventListener('mouseenter', changeColorOnTouch, false);
CIRCLE2.addEventListener('mouseenter', changeColorOnTouch2, false);


CIRCLE.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){CIRCLE.removeAttribute("style");}, false);
CIRCLE2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){CIRCLE2.removeAttribute("style");}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrxp2cm4/48/

Comment: "_circle_" is not a standard HTML element, what exactly is it?

Comment: one way to do this is to check if whether mouse is within element's bounds or not

Comment: you can achieve this in pure CSS. or you need JS solution?

Comment: @Teemu circle is just an example it can be any element

Comment: @Vaibhav can be pure CSS if it works for items intersecting and over each other as the fiddle example

Comment: Yes. Let me provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

Add a parent `div` and on its hover change CSS of children.

```css
.container:hover > .circle {
  background: #f55;
}
.container:hover > .circle2 {
  background: #5ff;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So while they both change color, they are not independent of each other, if my cursor is only over red, then only red should change, and if on blue then only blue should change. If my cursor is on both (intersection) then both should change color.

Comment: Okay, let me change

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse is in the inner Circle, the mouse is still in the outer circle, themouseleave would not trigger. You can't do it like that, there is a workaround however, you can manually set the color of the outer circle on the mouseenter for the inner circle.

here is the code

```
const c1 = document.getElementById('c1') // default color red
const c2 = document.getElementById('c2') // default color blue

c1.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => c1.style.background = 'black')
c2.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  c1.style.background = 'red'
  c2.style.background = 'white'
})

c1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => c1.style.background = 'red')
c2.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  c1.style.background = 'black'
  c2.style.background = 'blue' 
})
```

Comment: This solution works if they are completely over each other and not intersecting, like in the fiddle example.